# Pandas DataFrame isin(): How does conditional selection work in detail?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While working with pandas I ran into an issue which I can't quite explain.
Let me give an example where the DataFrame is called "reviews":

The following code doesn't run:

`reviews[(reviews["points"] >= 95) & (reviews["country"] in ["Australia"])]`

Instead one can use:

`reviews[(reviews["points"] >= 95) & (reviews["country"].isin(["Australia"]))]`

My first assumption was that this is caused by the way the bitwise operator `&` works,
but testing this I was suprised to find out the follwing line equals to True: `True & ("hi" in ["hi", "Hello"])`

Obviously `reviews["country"]` is not just a str. I guess with the operator `>=` some magic happens that is not implemented for `in`. Therefore, `isin()` is necessary.
Maybe someone can explain this further / better?

The example works with something like the following DataFrame:

```
    country     description     designation     points  
0   Italy       Aromas          Vulkà Bianco    87
```

This structure is basically taken from https://www.kaggle.com/learn/pandas lesson 2.9.

Error-MSG:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I believe `some_series in some_list` checks for the index of the series in the list or not. while `some_series.isin(some_list)` checks for values of the series.

Comment: Thanks. Can you think of an example where `some_series in some_list` is used correctly?

Answer (score 2):

`in` is a python keyword, while `isin` is a method for the Series which checks "whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values." [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: True, but the same logic doesn't appliy to `>=`. I wonder if there is some underlying reason for this design choice.